# GetRequiredService and AddHttpClient freeze .NET console application (stack overflow)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In my .NET Core console application, this line freezes:

`services.GetRequiredService<ISomething>();`

in the following code:

```
interface ISomething { }
class Cool : ISomething
{
    public Cool(IHttpClientFactory factory) { }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.StartAsync();

        // Freezes here and maxes out memory
        ISomething internalApiConnector = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ISomething>();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHttpClient<IHttpClientFactory>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISomething, Cool>();
            });
}
```

and ends up maxing out the memory with eventually crashes the app.
What am I missing?

Note:

- `Cool` constructor does not get run, so doesn't appear to be something halting in there.

**Solution (Thanks all)**:

`serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IHttpClientFactory>();` needed to be changed to
`serviceCollection.AddHttpClient();`

and

`.BuildServiceProvider()` was superflous.

Comment: Running .NET 5 and changing the following line `container.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);` works fine on my machine. Anything else that isn't in your example?

Comment: Also, in this example there isn't any need for calling `BuildServiceProvider()` in your own `IOCContainer`.

Comment: Long shot, is there anything in `cool` constructor which the container cannot resolve?

Comment: 1. I've decided to upgrade my visual studio as it was a bit behind (I'll tell you how that goes) .2. Thanks for the BuildServiceProvider note, i'll remove it and see if the provider is not null on the collection. :) .3. after the upgrade i'll make note of the .net 5 thing. I wonder what i'm on.

Comment: 1. BuildServiceProvider removed. Thanks. .2. AddHttpClient doesn't do what I thought it was doing. Thanks. I think that's the problem.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I just needed to call AddHttpClient() without any type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a stack overflow exception, caused by the `AddHttpClient<IHttpClientFactory>` registration. This causes a cyclic dependency which is not detected by MS.DI, causing the unfortunate stack overflow.

To understand why this happens, you need to look at the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/7c4f9479b4753a37c8b0669a883002e5e448cc94/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L326) for `HttpClientBuilderExtensions`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<TClient>(s =>
{
    var httpClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(builder.Name);

    var typedClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient>>();
    return typedClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClient);
});
```

As the code shows, a call to `AddHttpClient<TClient>` results in the registration of a delegate. When that delegate is invoked, an `IHttpClientFactory` is resolved. From that `IHttpClientFactory` an `HttpClient` is created. In your case, however, you specified `IHttpClientFactory` for your `TClient`, effectively replacing the original `IHttpClientFactory` registration. This caused the call to `s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()` to callback into itself, hence the cyclic dependency and the stack overflow.

To make this more concrete, if we replace `TClient` with `IHttpClientFactory`, which is basically what is happening in your code, you can see it more clearly:

```cs
// A registration for IHttpClientFactory is made
builder.Services.AddTransient<IHttpClientFactory>(s =>
{
    // When the delegate is called, IHttpClientFactory is resolved.
    var httpClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    ...
});
```

What you did wrong is supplying `IHttpClientFactory` as the `TClient` of `AddHttpClient<TClient>`. `AddHttpClient` is meant to register a 'client' class that takes a `HttpClient` as direct dependency. For instance:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<GitHubApiClient>() // GitHubApiClient depends on HttpClient
```

You, however, aren't the only party at fault here. Microsoft should have been a better job, because:

- MS.DI's cyclic-dependency detection is lacking and too simplistic causing it to miss this type of cyclic dependency.
- The `AddHttpClient<TClient>` method doesn't validate it's preconditions allowing this to happen. As it makes no sense to supply `AddHttpClient` with an abstract `TClient`, at the very least it should have prevented this and throw an exception.
- Further more, it makes no sense to register a `TClient` that contains no `HttpClient` as constructor dependency, so this should have been detected by AddHttpClient as well.

This means that there is room for improvement in the Microsoft stack ;-)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much. What an amazing response.